# Pagination in Angular2 (On Rails5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, pagination

Normally with Rails, I'd use `will_paginate` and call it a day, but I'm using Rails5 purely as an API, and front-end is completely Angular2.

I've looked into [NG Bootstrap4's Pagination](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination) but I'm having quite a few issues getting it to do anything besides render - And I can imagine why. What is the proper process for Paginating on Angular? I tried using will-paging to paginate the JSON but instead I just limit the results.

I also looked into [ng2-pagination](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ng2-pagination) which seemed to have a lot of the features I wanted, but I started getting
`Uncaught TypeError: ctorParameters.map is not a function` errors for everything so I thought maybe I should take it a step back.

Would the proper process be to use the controller in Rails to append a 'page' parameter to the JSON Results? Or would something more like Virtualization be the route I should go?

Having quite a few issues - Even once I have the bar active, it obviously can't control my script.

```
getDecks(): Observable<Deck[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.decksUrl)
                                    .map((response: Response) => <Deck[]>response.json())
                                    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

this is the call that contacts the API and gets the response - I feel like I would involve the 'page' here to actually allow Pagination to do something?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out - multiple issues. For those wondering:

`Uncaught TypeError: ctorParameters.map is not a function` seems to be a compilation issue with newer packages.

[Different library but similar issues](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular2-google-maps/issues/812)

I upgraded Ang2 + Respective libraries to remove error. From there the instructions made a lot more sense.

The pipe should be built directly into your `ngFor`

```
<span *ngFor="let deck of decks| paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p }" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
```

Then placing
`<pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>`
Where-ever you want an async bar resolves the issue.

Works perfectly - Library is [Ng2-Pagination](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ng2-pagination)